# Unable to replace stock photos on HTML website template for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, templates

I have downloaded a HTML website template. I am trying to customize it by replacing some of the pictures with my own.I have resized the new pictures to match the dimension of the originals. Once replaced, it shows perfectly in Chrome, but no image is displayed in IE. I have tried most formats (jpeg, gif, png, bmp). Any suggestions?

Comment: It's more likely that someone will be able to help you if you post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would be easier to help if you post some relevant code. And check the pictures names because sometimes some browsers have trouble displaying pictures with spaces in the name.